# Tutorials for ASP.NET MVC3 with IoC ,Repository patterns etc

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, dependency-injection, repository-pattern, autofac

I will start new project which is based on ASP.NET MVC 3 using C# and razor engine.
Before stating this project,I want to do some tutorials which is related to Repository pattern,Dependancy Injections Autofac and all these things that can make better code or and easy to maintain.

So Can you provide me some useful links or tutorials?

Comment: Stackoverflow is not an recommendation engine: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/ You are also asking several questions

Comment: If you want to read about repository, take [a look here](http://www.cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=84). If you want to read about designing easy to maintain applications, take a look [here](http://www.cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=91).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at [Full Stack](http://channel9.msdn.com/Series/The-Full-Stack). It covers everything you mentioned and more.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the source code for Orchard CMS, it includes all of the above.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if they use Autofac but [NerdDinner](http://nerddinnerbook.s3.amazonaws.com/Intro.htm) might be a good fit for you.